# VBCCR14.OCX error loading dll in VB6

Tags: dll, vb6, common-controls

I'm using VBCCR14.dll Activex Common Control in order to support Unicode. In the developed machine it works perfectly but when the program is running from a different machine it gives an error saying that, "Error loading dll". I've also registered the dll in the other machine but still it gives the error. I've also tried to solve this problem, by referring this article. 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?841929-VB6-ActiveX-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)
But still the error occurs. Could someone help me regarding this issue?
I've tried it with Visual basic 6.0 in Windows 10.

Comment: I assume the downvote is because this is a question for the owners of that project, on the forum you cite. But it may be (often is) that the DLL that errors has a dependency that isn't present on the target machine. DEPENDS.EXE is your friend.

Comment: you should please specify what OS and version is your target machine, as registering the VBCCR14.OCX on the deployment machine should work just fine.